# Does async always use another thread/core/process in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency

As I know `async` executes a function in another thread/process/core and doesn't block the main thread, but is that always the case?

I have following code:

```
async(launch::async,[]()
{
    Sleep(1000);
    puts("async");
});
puts("main");
```

It prints `async main`, so does that mean that the main thread waits until `async` finishes?

If I change to following:

```
auto f = async(launch::async,[]() // add "auto f = "
{
    Sleep(1000);
    puts("async");
});
puts("main");
```

It prints `main async`. This makes it seem like main doesn't wait for `async` to finish.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

> As I know async executes a function in another thread/process/core and don't block main thread, but does it happens always?

[`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) is guaranteed to execute on a separate thread only if [`std::launch::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch) is passed as the first argument:

> - `std::launch::async`: a new thread is launched to execute the task asynchronously
> - `std::launch::deferred` the task is executed on the calling thread the first time its result is requested (lazy evaluation)

The default *launch policy* is `std::launch::async | std::launch::deferred`.

---

`std::async` returns [`std::future`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future). [`std::future`'s destructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/future/~future) will block only if the future was returned from `std::async`:

> these actions will not block for the shared state to become ready, except that it may block if all of the following are true: the shared state was created by a call to std::async, the shared state is not yet ready, and this was the last reference to the shared state

---

- In your first code snippet, you create an *rvalue expression* **which is immediately destroyed** - therefore `"async"` will be printed before `"main"`.

  1. Async anonymous function is created and starts executing.
  2. Async anonymous function is destroyed.

     - `main` execution is blocked until the function is completed.
     - `"async"` is printed.
  3. `main` execuction resumes.

     - `"main"` is printed.

---

- In your second code snippet, you create an *lvalue expression* whose lifetime is bound to the variable `f`. **`f` will be destroyed at the end of the `main` function's scope** - therefore `"main"` will be printed before `"async"` due to the `Delay(1000)`.

  1. Async anonymous function is created and starts executing.

     - There's a `Delay(1000)` that delays `"async"` from being printed immediately.
  2. `main` execution continues.

     - `"main"` is printed.
  3. End of `main`'s scope.
  4. Async anonymous function is destroyed.

     - `main` execution is blocked until the function is completed.
     - `"async"` is printed.

Comment: `deferred` doesn't really seem useful unless you're in a case where you don't know if you'll even need the result later on.

Comment: @JAB: Lazy evaluation is considered useful enough that some languages are lazy evaluated by default ;)

Answer (score 7):

> It prints `async main`, so does that mean that the main thread waits until `async` finishes?

Yes it does, but that is because you do not capture the returned future from `async`.  `async` is special in that the `future` returned from it blocks in the destructor until the thread completes.  Since you do not capture the returned `future`

```
async(launch::async,[]()
{
    Sleep(1000);
    puts("async");
});
```

must finish before progress is made in the current thread as that returned `future` is destroyed at the end of the expression.

> It prints `main async`. This makes it seem like main doesn't wait for `async` to finish.

Which is what you really want when you call `async`.  Since you have captured the future your main thread is allowed to continue on while the asynchronis task is completed.  Since you have a delay in that thread `main` is going to print before the thread.

Answer (score 3):

If you pass `std::launch::async`, then `std::async` must run the task as if it was run in its own thread.

The only concept of threading in C++ is `std::thread`.

`std::async` returns a `std::future` with a unique property; if destroyed, it blocks on the completion of the task stored in `std::async`.  This traps you when you fail to capture the return value; the returned `std::future` is an unnamed temporary which comes into existence, and is destroyed at the "end of that line".

This destruction waits for the `async` task to complete.

In the case where you store it, this delay waits until the variable `f` is destroyed, which is at the end of `main`, which is after we print.

Note that at least one major implementation of C++11, MSVC 2015 and 2017, has an at best marginally compliant `std::async` that uses a thread pool instead of new threads.  This thread pool means that one set of long-running `async` calls can starve other `async` calls from running.

Using a thread pool is legal (so long as it recreates any thread-locals), but it should try to avoid starvation and create new threads if all of the existing threads are busy for "too long".

It is marginally compliant because the standard only states that threads "should" make forward progress.  Threads that never progress for random reasons is legal under C++; and in sense you could argue that is what `std::async` emulates in those cases, thus passing the as-if test.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the **destructor** of `std::future` (returned from `std::async`) waits its' task to complete.

In the first code snippet, temporary `std::future` object returned from `std::async` is destroyed at the end of the statement, because as written in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime

> All temporary objects are destroyed as the last step in evaluating the
>   full-expression that (lexically) contains the point where they were
>   created

Therefore, before executing the next statement, the destructor of the `std::future` object blocks until the task completes which means `puts("async")` is executed before `puts("main")`.

However, in the second code snippet, return value of std::async is **moved** into a local object, which is destroyed when exiting the scope. Therefore the line with the `async` is executed without block and the `puts("main")` is executed before `puts("async")` (which is blocked by the `Sleep` call) as expected.

This behavior is explained in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async as:

> If the std::future obtained from std::async is not moved from or bound
>   to a reference, the destructor of the std::future will block at the
>   end of the full expression until the asynchronous operation completes,
>   essentially making code such as the following synchronous:

```
std::async(std::launch::async, []{ f(); }); // temporary's dtor waits for f()
std::async(std::launch::async, []{ g(); }); // does not start until f() completes
```

In *Item 38* of the book [Effective Modern C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491903996), this is expressed as:

> The destructor for the last future referring to a shared state for a
>   non-deferred task launched via std::async blocks until the task
>   completes. In essence, the destructor for such a future does an
>   implicit join on the thread on which the asynchronously executing task
>   is running.